# Moon rotation tidal braking

Tags: the-moon, rotation

Do we know if the moon had an initial rotation or did it coalesce tidally locked. If it had an initial rotation how long would it take to become tidally locked?

Comment: The Moon most likely had a unlocked rotation. See this [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) and maybe my recent answer to [this Worldbuilding question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/169281/62241) for attempting to solve for a tidal locking timescale.

Comment: [The Moon became tidally “locked” within 100 million years](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2018/07/11/what-did-the-moon-look-like-from-earth-4-billion-years-ago/#1b6480811151) of it's formation. I guess this would be based on a calculation like that of @BMFForMonica .